# Post data on database using query String

Tags: android, mysql, database

I have to post my data to database and using query String to pass the value.I have done it through asynctask but data is not posting on database-:

TelephonyInfo telephonyInfo = TelephonyInfo.getInstance(this);

```
    String imeiSIM1 = telephonyInfo.getImeiSIM1();
    String imeiSIM2 = telephonyInfo.getImeiSIM2();

    boolean isSIM1Ready = telephonyInfo.isSIM1Ready();
    boolean isSIM2Ready = telephonyInfo.isSIM2Ready();

    final boolean isDualSIM = telephonyInfo.isDualSIM();

  class MainThread extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>{
            protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {

                HttpClient http = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
try {

                HttpResponse response = http.execute(post);
               // responseString = new BasicResponseHandler().handleResponse(response); // Basic handler

                //return true;
                }
                catch (ClientProtocolException e) { 
                }
                catch (IOException e){
                } 

//              return null;
                return true;
                            }

            public void execute(String url) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                MainThread thread=new MainThread();
                thread.execute(url);
                }
        };
}
}
```

Please help me out to resolve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: are of getting any exception toward android side?

Comment: source Not found inside ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity

Comment: http://pastie.org/8549308    logcat is here

Comment: cant open access denied, paste you logcat here itself !

Comment: Its so long.all warning, no any error

Comment: http://pastie.org/pastes/8549308/text